# Lightning Chart Ohlc Series

Tags: lightningchart

How do I test the ohlc series, I cannot see any demo in lightningchart official site.

I tried below code

```
candle[id] = chart[id].addOHLCSeries().setMouseInteractions(false);
```

Also previously when I checked ohlcseries of lighning chart ,,  candle automatically converting to different candles when i zoom in , how to disable that.I want to preserve the candles of my data.. maybe can reduce width of candles reduce when i zoom in.. but not automatically create.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/troubleshooting/restricted-features/#ohlc-series

OHLCSeries is a feature specific to Trading industry, it is restricted to users who have explicitly bought the product for Trading use cases.

For access and more information, you'll have to [contact](https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/contact/) LightningChart directly.

Comment: yea ok, I was just seeing examples and everything is broken not rendering any ohlc charts.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by broken examples.